# ionic emulate ios not working

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

hey everyone getting into ionic framework and im trying to emulate my app thru an iphone
runnin the following command from the terminal
`ionic emulate ios`
and get the follow error

```
• You're trying to build for ios but don't have the platform installed yet.
∆ Installing ios for you.

 Error: Command failed: cordova platform add ios
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:206:12)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:334:11)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:498:12)`
```

been looking around and havent found anything solid to fix the issue, looking for any help possible

Answer (score 0):

You have to try to remove the ios platform and then add it again:

```
ionic platform rm ios

ionic platform add ios
```

Comment: getting this error message after i run `ionic platform add ios` Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/bchanhthasenh/ionic/weedMeApp/platforms/ios'

Comment: if you face access problem.

Comment: Try running the following command on your directory, this will change the permissions to your regular account so you shouldn't require sudo to run your commands.

sudo chown -R $USER /your-directory/

Comment: `Error: Source path does not exist: resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png` is my error after your instructions on `chown`

Comment: If you are missing the icon you can run the command

1.ionic resources --icon

This will generate all the icons with the pixels needed to run on any device.

To simulate on the device you first need to 

2.ionic build ios


and then

3.ionic simulate ios


If you are still getting the error you can paste this line

"$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include"

on Build Settings > Header Search Paths. Do not remove the similar line, just add it at the end.